# How to fix 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence' in numpy arrays with an inhomogeneous shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
board_1 = np.array(game_board)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (6, 7) + inhomogeneous part.

Process finished with exit code 1

how can i fix this error?

Comment: fix `game_board`

Comment: `np.array(game_board, dtype=object)`

Comment: What is `game_board`?  What array shape and dtype do you exprect.  You don't provide enough information.